# How to conditionally lookup from a collection based on type (mongo 4.4)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Below is an aggregation with some of mid pipelines

```
[
 {
    $unwind: "$destinations"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "customers",
      localField: "destinations.sold_to_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "sold_to_ref"
    },
    
  },
]
```

As per the above query, `destinations` is an array which will be like

```
[{
   type: 1,
   sold_to_id: 'xxxxx'
 },
 {
  type: 2,
  sold_to_id: 'yyyy',
 }
]
```

Now I want to perform the lookup based on the type (ie)
if type = 1, then lookup from `customers`
else lookup from `users`.
Note: `customers` and `users` are two different collections

Please help me out in this.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

The solution that I tried

```
[{
    $unwind: "$destinations"
},
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "customers",
      "let": {
        type: "$destinations.type",
        destination_id: "$destinations.sold_to_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$$type", 1 ] }, // Here I need to compare the type value with 1 which is not happening
                         { $eq: [ "$_id", "$$destination_id" ] }
                       ]
                    }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "sold_to_ref"
    },
    
  }]
```

Edit:
If the input collections are like

```
db={
  "collection": [
    { 
      "contact": [
        'adf', 'dsf', 'sdd'],
      "destinations": [
        {
          type: 1,
          sold_to_id: "xxxxx"
        },
        {
          type: 1,
          sold_to_id: "yyyy"
        },
        {
          type: 2,
          sold_to_id: "zzz"
        },
        {
          type: 2,
          sold_to_id: "www"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "customers": [
    {
      _id: "xxxxx",
      name: "Customer1"
    },
    {
      _id: "yyyy",
      name: "Customer2"
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      _id: "zzz",
      name: "User1"
    },
    {
      _id: "www",
      name: "User2"
    }
  ]
}
```

then result should be as below

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "contact": [
        'adf', 'dsf', 'sdd'],
      "destinations": [
        {
          type: 1,
          sold_to_id: "xxxxx",
          sold_to_ref: "Customer1"
        },
        {
          type: 1,
          sold_to_id: "yyyy",
          sold_to_ref: "Customer2"
        },
        {
          type: 2,
          sold_to_id: "zzz",
          sold_to_ref: "User1"
        },
        {
          type: 2,
          sold_to_id: "www",
          sold_to_ref: "User2"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: are there any fields that connect between the two tables destination and customers/users

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fk8vpjCm9R9). if this works i can give an answer

Comment: Yes but I need a solution that is compatible with mongo 4.4

Comment: didnt know it didnt support 4.4. u are only doing 1 lookup. also no foreignField relation?

Comment: ya will be adding another lookup below pointing to users collection.

Comment: there is a connection, inside the pipeline, variables prefixed with $$ are local fields and variable prefixed with $ are foreign fields.
Thats the reason why passing 1 doesn't work

Comment: arent the $$ s the variables defined inside the let?

Comment: As you can see only localField and other local variables are defined inside let

Comment: but doesnt this just add the whole customer collection inside the `"sold_to_ref"` if you don't specify connected localField and foreignField. sorry its just too hard to visualize without seeing data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Not possible (not even in SQL).

**Workaround:** You run 2 `LEFT JOINS` with `$facet`, merge them and flatten the result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      customers: [
        {
          $addFields: {
            destinations: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$destinations",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.type",
                    1
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "customers",
            localField: "destinations.sold_to_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "sold_to_ref"
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            "sold_to_ref.0": {
              $exists: true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      users: [
        {
          $addFields: {
            destinations: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$destinations",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.type",
                    2
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "destinations.sold_to_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "sold_to_ref"
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            "sold_to_ref.0": {
              $exists: true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      merge: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$users",
          "$customers"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$merge"
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        "$merge",
        {
          "copy": "$merge.destinations"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$copy"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      copy: "$$REMOVE",
      sold_to_ref: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$sold_to_ref",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$copy.sold_to_id",
              "$$this._id"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c_EBIYkFG-B)

Comment: I have one concern with this solution, for each entry in the collections, there will be other attributes as well which I can project, in addition to that I should be able to project the entire destination array as well.

Comment: In other words I need to preserve the destination array. I have edited my question with a sample input and expected output. Please check

Comment: @Amaarockz I've updated my answer. Check if it meets your requirements